# Run android helloworld failed in intellij idea

Tags: android, intellij-idea, genymotion

It works in google avd,but when I run in genymotion,it failed.And here is the output message:

```
Installing com.example.test2
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.test2"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.test2
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]
```

What can I do ? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the the version of android of the simulator is higher than the minimum version specified for app in AndroidManifest.xml.

To fix change the minSdkVersion to a number less than or equal to the version of the android of the simulator.

Eg: If you are running Android 4.1.1 (API 16) on the simulator make sure the following entry in AnndroidManifest has proper value

Answer (score 0):

Is Genymotion running the same version of Android as the AVD? Looks like Genymotion is running an older version.

Comment: But it works in eclipse,I think there need some settings between intellij idea and genymotion.